# What does the hierarchy in NPM's package-lock.json represent?

Tags: npm

Each dependency optionally has a `dependencies` property and a `requires` property. These are not necessarily both present, and their contents do not necessarily overlap.  I assume `requires` holds anything listed in the `package.json` for that package, but I can't find any reference which properly describes the `dependencies` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packages at each level are shared by other packages on that branch of the dependency tree. If a child package uses a different version of a package then it will be duplicated at that point of the tree.

I've deduced this with a little poking around the contents of a `package-lock.json` and by inferring from [npm dedupe](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dedupe).